# Why does the first random value just increase every time I run the code?

Tags: c, random, random-seed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    printf("%d\n", rand()%100+1);
    printf("%d", rand()%100+1);

    return 0;
}
```

I've run this many times and each time the first value just increased steadily, like `2 5 9 17 24 30 ..... 91 97 3 7 12` (but the value is always different). Strangely, the second value performed normally, what could be the reason?

I'm using Dev-C++ and TDM-GCC 4.9.2

Comment: What platform and compiler version are you using? `rand()` is often implemented pretty badly. Use `random()` if you can, and seed it with `srandom()`.

Comment: @Thomas I'm using Dev-C++ and TDM-GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: With a simple linear congruential generator like most `rand()` implementations use, a steadily increasing seed value like the time is going to produce a steadily increasing first number, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much right, I also don't know the exact or correct reason of this happening.

But I fixed this issue with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (;;) // running infinitely here until program's interrupted
    {
        printf("%d\n", rand() % 100 + 1);
        printf("%d", rand() % 100 + 1);
        printf("\n---\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you put `srand(time(NULL))` outside the infinite loop and everything else inside it, it'll work correctly. After this, you'll get both values changed randomly in each iteration rather than just increasing (the first value).

Comment: Everything I just did I had inserted those two `printf()` into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your root cause is likely that C's old random number generator is not really that good. In my mind it's primary use cases are when quality is not important or you need the ability to repeat "random number" series to assure test results, and the like, can compare well over time. These "pseudo random number generators" have forever been a sore spot to projects needing good random numbers.

If you need true good stuff you can obtain random numbers using:

1. Entropy based features found on most popular operating systems, like the /dev/urandom family of random devices on unix-like systems. Microsoft Windows has something as well but I've forgotten it.
2. Internet random number services like random.org (obviously not for high-volume numbers). They have APIs so programs can automate the experience, which would be educational but be sure to follow the guidelines.
3. Hardware random number generators (search for: usb random numbers) if  you really want quality or quantity.

Historically using just the low-order bits of rand() values tends to amplify the defects, which may help get what you saw. I've posted a second answer that goes into the nuts and bolts of improving on the performance of rand().

Answer (score 0):

Try run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        srand(i);
        printf("%d\n", rand()%100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you get a pure increasing list, then it's because your randomness returns seed at the first run.

To fix it, call a `rand()` just after `srand` and ignore its value. It'll somehow seem to improve the randomness.

Comment: It worked. But I just don't understand why the second value in my code didn't get affected by the seed-related problems.

Comment: @rookie, you are using a random seed that is the result of calling the `time(3)` function, this makes your seed (and so, the first random value) to be monotonically increasing as time does, and not random at all :)

Comment: @LuisColorado I don't know. Why does this not happen to the second value in my code? The second value seems pretty random.

Comment: @rookie Some extra function is run after returning the first random number, making it seems pretty random.

Comment: @rookie, because the first is provided by you, based on the time of the day (so it shows monotonically incrementing) but the second is the first pseudo-random number produced by the `rand()` routine, so it must show some randomnes (some unpredictability)

Answer (score -1):

On top of the defective nature of most rand() implementations mentioned in my first answer on broader issues of random numbers there is also a subtle problem in your %100.  As RAND_MAX is usually a power of two, say 32767, using just the last two digits will slightly favor lower values as there will be the potential of missing 68-99 some some calls. To get uniform 00-99 distributions you would need to go to 32799, which is not going to happen.

A better solution would be to do something to get a random value from 0.0 to 0.999999... in a way that uses all bits and then expand on that:

```
          //untested code alert:
double  rand01 = (double)(rand()%RAND_MAX) / (double)RAND_MAX; // get zero up to but not including one
printf( "%d\n", 1 + int(100.0 * rand01) );
```

This uses all the available bits in the returned random numbers.

Software generated random numbers have always been a pain-point in computers.

Comment: "using just the last two digits will slightly favor lower values as there will be the potential of missing 68-99 some some calls"

Comment: Do you mean it might lose those values in some calls?

Comment: Not so much loose them as never had them,l at least for 16-bit values, which I used for simplicity. Different integer types have different ranges. Non-negative signed values run from all zeros to a 0 followed by all 1's. For 32-bit values will run through 0-2147483647, which doesn't have 48-99 as it's last values. The range is now so much larger it statistically matters very littile that those are missing. However using low-order bits is still a poor idea.

If you want more details on integers look into stdint.h (as at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdint.h).